# target_include_directories not including INTERFACE library

Tags: c++, cmake

```
# Adding a header-only library
set(INCLUDE_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include")
add_library(myLib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(myLib INTERFACE "${INCLUDE_LOCATION}")

# Printing the include paths for the header only target
get_target_property(dirs myLib INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
    message(STATUS "dir='${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

The above cmake will show `dir=NOTFOUND`

There are no problems with `${INCLUDE_LOCATION}`, I have checked it.

This works perfectly fine if I swap the library to executable.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface libraries don't have non-`INTERFACE` properties. `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` is simply invalid here.

You are looking for `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(test)

set(INCLUDE_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include")
add_library(myLib INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(myLib INTERFACE "${INCLUDE_LOCATION}")

get_target_property(dirs myLib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir IN LISTS dirs)
    message(STATUS "dir='${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

Prints:

```
-- dir='/home/reinking/test/../include'
```